# Typesense docsearch un docusaurus

Tags: algolia, docusaurus, typesense

The main problem is that there is not much information on how to implement typesense docsearch on a website made with ducusaurus.  Is it very similar to doing it with algolia, maybe the .env and config.json part?

Following the steps in the docusaurus documentation, it turns out that these steps are or are very similar to do it with algolia, however, something is wrong, I am missing something within the configuration.  I do not know what it is

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a detailed guide on how to setup DocSearch with Typesense and Docusaurus: https://typesense.org/docs/guide/docsearch.html